# Why this toggle menu dont work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a toggle menu and it looks really nice,but when i tried it,it didnt worked as i expected,because he is not toggling:

Here is the original script [click](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uvCbg)

Even if i just copy and paste it,it still not working and i dont know why (here is another try in jsfiddle)[click](http://jsfiddle.net/3az75L1e/) 
First i thought it must be something with the syntax:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

But after i tried in jsfiddle too,i realize its not and i cant figure out what seems to be the problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you havn't loaded the jQuery library.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: and how can i do that? sorry but i didnt read anything about js...

Comment: I don't use jQuery myself but a quick google search gave me this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: thanks i will accept your answer in 5 minutes

Comment: This answer looks more like a comment. However it would be more beneficial to other users if you can include a snippet of code that shows how to load jQuery into a page

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line to your html file above your script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

It's the latest jQuery version.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have the jquery library added in your script

See

http://jsfiddle.net/3az75L1e/2/`see`